# When you're the first person to contact

Tags: single-word-requests

When you're the first person to contact clients/respond to request/ etc, you're "what"?

What's the correct word for this person? To be at line of fire ?

Comment: "First line" support (fairly neutral term) or "in the line of fire" (slightly negative) meaning you are the one to have to deal with the positive, or, more likely negative, consequences of whatever you have to say to the client.

Comment: I'm afraid you used the wrong tag. Please supply a sample sentence using the word you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for [point of contact](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point_of_contact) (abbreviated POC):

> The single person who represents an organization, for a specific task.

For example:

> I am the point of contact for customer service requests.

Comment: Another variation would be SPoC or **S**ingle **P**oint **O**f **C**ontact.